# How to move a a UIImageView around a predetermined point?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiimageview

It's a rather difficult question to explain. I followed a tutorial on moving an image view with touch, and what it does is gets the touch location and moves the *center* of the image to that touch location. Now, I want to detect where the user tapped relative to the entire screen, and where the user tapped relative to the image's coordinates. I want to move the image around from there. In other words, if I tap on an image, I don't want it to immediately jump to my cursor. If that doesn't make sense, here's the original source code below. I'm fairly new to iOS programming, but I do know the basic fundamentals and things like that.

Original Code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
    touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)

    // this line isn't important, it just determines which part of the image the user is able to select.
    currentPart = partsArray[currentPartNum]

    currentPart?.center = touchLocation
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
    touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)

    // this line isn't important, it just determines which part of the image the user is able to select.
    currentPart = partsArray[currentPartNum]

    currentPart?.center = touchLocation
}
```

Now how can I determine the point tapped relative to the image, and move it along that? Sorry if it's a difficult question, thank you for answering/considering to answer.

Comment: I'd say the whole tutorial is misguided if the view jumps to put its center where the first tap is.

Comment: When you say "move image view *around* a predetermined point" it makes me think you want to rotate the image around that point. Is that what you mean, or are you saying that you want to be able to touch down on an image and start sliding the image around on the screen like you would do with a paper photograph on a table? (So if you touch down anywhere and then slide your finger 1 CM to the right, the image slides 1 CM to the right, then if you slide 2 CM up, the image slides up 2 CM, leaving it shifted 1 CM to the right and 2 CM up from it's original position?)

Comment: Duncan C, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Currently, what this code does, is if you had a photo on a table, and you put your finger on the top left corner of the photo, the center of the photo would jump to your finger before you started sliding it around.